# Count each value appearance in one row and get 3rd corresponding value from another row

Tags: sql, sql-server, filtering

I have database with table as shown in picture.

Column `N` contains repeating values, each must be counted for how many times each appears in database.

If count is `>=10`, then appropriate **3rd largest value** from column P should be found, e.g. for `100288414` it is `10.3432543886119`. Then corresponding values from `N`, `W` and `P` copied and pasted into another table. And so on until the end of database.

How can I do it in mssql?

[image: Database]

[image: Result]

Comment: are you sure you have attached correct images..?

Comment: Your description and your images don't match -- making it really hard to understand your question.  It is better to put the data in as text tables.

Comment: my bad, uploaded coorect images

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select ID, N, W, P from (
    select ID, N, W, P,
           row_number() over (partition by N order by P desc) rn,
           count(ID) over (partition by N) cnt
    from TBL
) a where cnt >= 10 and rn = 3
```

Above will return 3rd greatest value accordingly to `P` column if there are no less than 10 entries for particular value in `N` column.

Comment: Thanks but this one returns error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: @Zazvata I am happy I could help. If answer solved your problem you should accept it and optionally upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with two queries that do the part of the job, First

`select n, count(*) as N FROM mytable GROUP BY n;`

returns how many times value from column n appears in table and second returns 
1-2-3 highest values

`WITH cte AS 
( SELECT n, p, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n 
                                 ORDER BY p ASC ) 
                     AS rn 
      FROM mytable 
) 
SELECT n, p, rn 
FROM cte 
WHERE rn <= 3 
ORDER BY n, rn ;`

But I cant figure out how to add data from column w and merge these queries into one